# Rapid Miner 101

Tags: java, rapidminer

I'm back with a question. I'm playing with Rapid Miner for automatic text classification and cant get it work. I'm getting an error that says, "no example set in the example, offending operator Performance ". Any idea what that is referring to ?

Answer (score 1):

In RapidMiner you have to use the converter components before using it as example sets. So, if you have an output as 'doc', for example, you have to use the component 'Documents to Data' in order to link it to the next input 'exa'. That´s all!

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details about your RapidMiner text mining process?
Without more context, your question is difficult to answer.

For more help with RapidMiner, you may want to check out the RapidMiner user forum: http://forum.rapid-i.com/

At RapidMiner Resources, you can find RapidMiner tutorial videos about how to text mining with RapidMiner: 
http://rapidminerresources.com/index.php?page=text-mining-3

Rapid-I also offers a 90 minutes text mining webinar. You can find it at the Rapid-I web page under "services" and "training" or in the web shop.

I hope these links help you to get started with automatic text classification with RapidMiner. If you provide more details about your RapidMiner text mining process, I may also be able to directly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it says that there is no Example Set, then the issue is probably with your original data. Can you post an image of your process?

For instance, make sure that you have connected the initial input to your operator - what two operators does the error occur at?

One thought: the example set in text mining is usually your document collection, but if you are really using documents (PDF, Word) then your format will be Documents (Doc), and you may need to transform your documents to data (Documents to Data operator). Then you should have an Example Set that you can feed into your Performance operator.

Hope this helps - as the earlier comment said, without knowing the process, it is hard to tell exactly where the error is.